# How can I user ConnectionProvider/Consumer with WebParts that use RegisterInterface?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm writing new web parts that need to communicate with pre-existing third-party webparts. If I use RegisterInterface to provide a connection point, I can set up connections between my new web part and the third-party ones. However, so far I haven't been able to manage that using ConnectionProvider/ConsumerAttribute -- the connections declared via the attributes show up, but they are grayed out, which seems to imply that they are incompatible.

(Now, I could use RegisterInterface, seeing as it works just fine, but I don't like seeing the compiler warnings from using obsolete methods.)

Note that I'm a Sharepoint newbie, so I'm probably just not doing this right. However, if someone could point out the things I need to take into account when doing this, or even if this is possible to begin with, I'd be very grateful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the 3rd party web parts in question did, in fact, contain support for 3.0-style connections. I was trying to consume an IRowProvider, when the correct interface was, in fact, IWebPartRow.